# Thread-safety of INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, concurrency

MySQL statement:

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

appears like a single statement that should be thread-safe (in the sense that no concurrent query on the same data can happen during its execution). But on the other hand, it could be internally decomposed into `insert` and `update` statements, and I'm wondering if it's still guaranteed to be thread safe?

I mean, for example, could there be a `delete` in between the `insert`and `update` coming from a concurrent thread that would cause the `update` to fail?

I think `insert on duplicate key update` should be thread safe, but the docs do not seem to state it in clear text. Could anyone please provide a proof link on the subject? How is it internally implemented?

Comment: I suppose locking will come to play and another query will have to wait. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52020

Comment: That´s exactly what happens, the system locks the row as if it was a transaction and it doesn´t unlock until the update has finished

Comment: RDBMSs use locks and isolation levels to control how parallelly running sessions can access the same data. There is no such thing as thread safety. Also, you should specify which storage engine within mysql you are referring to. Myisam and innodb implement features completely differently.

Comment: I agree, in this context the term "thread safety" may not be exact. Maybe I should have used "session safety", but it sounds weird :) anyway I hope you have understood what I meant. As for the RDBMS, I'm currently using InnoDB but I want to be aware of how other systems work as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RDBMSs use locks and isolation levels to control how parallelly running sessions can access the same data. There is no such thing as thread safety, nor session safety. There is only concurrency control.

If you use the myisam table type, then all data modification statements [lock the entire table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#internal-table-level-locking) (myisam can do concurrent inserts under limited circumstances, but the delete does require a table lock all the time). Therefore, a delete cannot interfere with an `insert ... on duplicate key update...`.

If you use the innodb table type, then the situation is a bit more complex because it applies row level locks. As mysql manual says on the [locks set by various sql statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html):

> INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE differs from a simple INSERT in that an exclusive lock rather than a shared lock is placed on the row to be updated when a duplicate-key error occurs. An exclusive index-record lock is taken for a duplicate primary key value. An exclusive next-key lock is taken for a duplicate unique key value.

So, first mysql locks the new record for the insert. If a duplicate key error occures, only then is the duplicate record locked. Technically, it is possible that between the duplicate key error and placing the exclusive lock on the duplicate record, a delete statement removes the duplicate record. However, this will not make the update statement fail. It will simply not update any records.

But this would require a very accurate timing of the delete statement.

The `insert ... on duplicate key update...` statement may fail only if the delete statement acquires the exclusive lock on the duplicate record after the duplicate key error and holds the lock so long that the insert's transaction times out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It turns out that the locks are being used internally, all over the place! I used to think INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE was a lock-less and transaction-less and therefore cheap way (in terms of avoiding bottlenecks due to waiting) of controlling concurrent access. Now it turns out that it's not all that lockless and cheap. Is it still the best way of doing "upsert" on MySQL, if I'm building a system with low latency in mind?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you have a new question, then you need to post it as a new question. But first search SO for the answer because there are dozens of questions on upsert in mysql comparing the different methods of performing upserts.

Comment: Also, it means that the answer to my original question is NO, i.e. INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not guaranteed to happen in isolation from concurrent sessions. It is therefore equivalent (in sense of concurrency) to sending two separate statements INSERT and UPDATE if the first insert fails. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct. See the quoted section in my answer.

Comment: It's different in the implementation (exclusive lock instead of shared lock) but from client's point of view, the possibility that the statement will end with no record (deleted) is still not entirely removed, though perhaps becomes less probable. Correct?